# How to find the maximum value of a function in Sympy?

Tags: max, sympy, computer-algebra-systems

These days I am trying to redo shock spectrum of single degree of freedom system using Sympy. The problem can reduce to find maximum value of a function. Following are two cases I cannot figure out how to do.

The first one is

```
tau,t,t_r,omega,p0=symbols('tau,t,t_r,omega,p0',positive=True)
h=expand(sin(omega*(t-tau)))
f=simplify(integrate(p0*tau/t_r*h,(tau,0,t_r))+integrate(p0*h,(tau,t_r,t)))
```

The final goal is to obtain maximum absolute value of `f` (The variable is `t`). The direct way is

```
df=diff(f,t)
sln=solve(simplify(df),t)
simplify(f.subs(t,sln[1]))
```

Here is the result, I tried many ways, but I can not simplify any further.

[image: Result]

Therefore, I tried another way. Because I need the maximum absolute value and the location where `abs(f)` is maximum happens at the same location of square of `f`, we can calculate square of `f` first.

```
df=expand_trig(diff(expand(f)**2,t))
sln=solve(df,t)
simplify(f.subs(t,sln[2]))
```

It seems the answer is almost the same, just in another form.

[image: Result]

The expected answer is a `sinc` function plus a constant as following:

[image: Expected]

Therefore, the question is how to get the final presentation.

The second one may be a little harder. The question can be reduced to find the maximum value of `f=sin(pi*t/t_r)-T/2/t_r*sin(2*pi/T*t)`, in which `t_r` and `T` are two parameters. The maximum located at different peak when the ratio of `t_r` and `T` changes. And I do not find a way to solve it in Sympy. Any suggestion? The answer can be represented in following figure.

[image: Max]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `log(exp(I*omega*t_r/2))` term. SymPy is not reducing this to `I*omega*t_r/2`. SymPy doesn't simplify this because in general, `log(exp(x)) != x`, but rather `log(exp(x)) = x + 2*pi*I*n` for some integer `n`. But in this case, if you replace `log(exp(I*omega*t_r/2))` with `omega*t_r/2` or `omega*t_r/2 + 2*pi*I*n`, it will be the same, because it will just add a `2*pi*I*n` inside the `sin`.

I couldn't figure out any functions that force this simplification, but the easiest way is to just do a substitution:

```
In [18]: print(simplify(f.subs(t,sln[1]).subs(log(exp(I*omega*t_r/2)), I*omega*t_r/2)))
p0*(omega*t_r - 2*sin(omega*t_r/2))/(omega**2*t_r)
```

That looks like the answer you are looking for, except for the absolute value (I'm not sure where they should come from).

Comment: Thanks! How about the second one, Sympy does not give a general solution for triangular equations. How can I get maximum value of "sin(pi*t/t_r)-T/2/t_r*sin(2*pi/T*t)" for different ratios of "t_r" and "T"?